# FXM - How to delete placeholders

Tags: placeholders, fxm

I no longer need these `placeholders`. How can I delete them?

[image]

While adding the second `placeholder`, mistakenly, I selected `Replace` which is overlapping some text and now I do not see an option to delete.

Comment: go to content editor and delete it from there

Comment: @SitecorePro  Would appreciate if you could give the complete answer. Do you mean in `/sitecore/layout/placeholder settings`? If yes, then I did and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: go to /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/FXM, this is where your fxm site lives. select the placeholder and delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage placeholders and other FXM-related things from here -

```
/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/FXM
```

[image]

You can follow below link to know more about placeholders - https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/add-a-placeholder-on-an-external-website-in-fxm.html